# Twilio: Sms, queueing and subaccounts

Tags: twilio

So we are developing a service that will ultimately send sms messages to Twilio.  We currently have a corporate account we are being asked to use and will be using a subaccount to separate the usage metrics.

New messages are queued, queues back up, queues can overflow (throwing back the 30001 error). My question is: do we share a queue with the primary account to which we are subaccount to?  Our app has "back down" logic that attempts to slow down posts to Twilio if we get back the queue overflow error.  But our parent account doesn't, we can't manage the 'back down' policy of the other sub accounts.

My question, does each subaccount get its own queue that is insulated against the possible ridonculous behavior of the other subaccounts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Megan from Twilio here.

Subaccounts are a way to segment this activity.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts

And a [Queue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue) is specific to the account that they come from. So yes, they are insulated as you ask.